# CheckBoxList not outputing the label

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, checkboxlist

In one of my ASP.Net and Sitecore CMS based page I am using CheckBoxList control but somehow it's not outputting the label in the HTML.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkListBrochure" CssClass="checkbox_single" />
```

In Code behind file I am loading the list:

```
foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
            var newListItem = new ListItem(item.Title, item.Code);
            newListItem.Selected = item.Selected;
            chkListBrochure.Items.Add(newListItem);
        }
```

When I view the code in the browser it appears as

```
<div id="body_0_content_0_content_1_chkListBrochure" class="checkbox_single">
  <input id="body_0_content_0_content_1_chkListBrochure_0" class="" type="checkbox"    
      name="body_0$content_0$content_1$chkListBrochure$0">
  <input id="body_0_content_0_content_1_chkListBrochure_1" class="" type="checkbox" 
     checked="checked" name="body_0$content_0$content_1$chkListBrochure$1">
  <input id="body_0_content_0_content_1_chkListBrochure_2" class="" type="checkbox" 
     name="body_0$content_0$content_1$chkListBrochure$2">
  <input id="body_0_content_0_content_1_chkListBrochure_3" class="" type="checkbox" 
     checked="checked" name="body_0$content_0$content_1$chkListBrochure$3">
  <input id="body_0_content_0_content_1_chkListBrochure_4" class="" type="checkbox" 
     name="body_0$content_0$content_1$chkListBrochure$4">
  <input id="body_0_content_0_content_1_chkListBrochure_5" class="" type="checkbox" 
     checked="checked" name="body_0$content_0$content_1$chkListBrochure$5">
</div>
```

It works fine if I copy this code in a non Sitecore based project. Is there anyone come across this problem? any suggestion?

Thanks

Nas

Comment: I think we need more information. Var datatype is itemList and what are item.Selected and item.Code? Are they extension methods you've made to get field values? Does item.Id work

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, a CheckBoxList renders just fine on my Sitecore 6.5 box.

The output of your CheckBoxList is not standard. The default `asp:CheckBoxList` control renders the checkboxes in a `table` not a `div`. Even if you change `RepeatLayout="Flow"` on your `<ASP:CheckBoxList` tag you would still not get a `div`; on my testing I got a `span`.

I would image you have a control adapter, or something, modifying the output.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `ListItem` control in `System.Web.UI.WebControls` but also there is a Sitecore control called `ListItem` in `Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls`. Could there be some confusion in your code as to which one you are referring to ?

Comment: Using the Sitecore ListItem would provide compilation errors as there is no constructor, at least in Sitecore 6.5, taking two arguments. Furthermore, you can't add a Sitecore ListItem to the ASP:CheckBoxList items.